# How to use blob from Azure Storage in Puppeteer function?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, puppeteer

Right now I have an Azure Function that runs Puppeteer to fill out some forms. At one page, I need to upload a pdf. Until now, I've been using a test pdf that's deployed to the same directory as the function, meaning I could do something similar to the Puppeteer documentation for waitForFileChooser:

```
const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
   page.waitForFileChooser(),
   page.click('#upload-file-button'),
]);
await fileChooser.accept(['/data/myfile.pdf']);
```

But I would like the file I upload to be one chosen by the user that is uploaded and stored in a blob container.

I tried to `downloadToFile(userInput.filename);` but Azure is a read only system. Is there a way around this? Can I pass a blob into a fileChooser like this, or make my directory rw but clear it out at the end of the function?

Comment: I may not be fully understanding, is `downloadBlobToFile()` from [this resource on GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download-javascript.md)? So there are some other methods that you could try, including `downloadBlobToString()` and `downloadBlobToStream()`. Downloading the blob to a stream or string could put the into a `JavaScript` variable or `<input type="hidden" value="${blob_data}" />` and them submit that.

Comment: I've downloaded the Blob to a Javascript File object, but I can't figure out how to pass that to a html file input. It seems like that behaviour might be blocked for security reasons based on some other questions I've seen?